# Insert data into an SQL Server 2008 table from a form in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

This is what I have done:

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=user-ade4de77d3;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;uid=sa;pwd=sql2008");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT  into person VALUES (@empid,@name,@sex,@mstatus,@empstat,@dob,@doh,@dor,@dot)");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", txtid.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", dpsex.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mstatus", dpmstat.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empstat", dpstatus.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", txtdob.Text );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doh", txtdoh.Text );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dor", txtdor.Text );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dot", txtdot.Text );
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I'm getting an error like this:

> No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.

How do I clear this error?

Comment: I sure hope you're **not really** using the `sa` user in your production code!!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam.Text);
```

as your version is missing the `.Text` off the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam);
```

should be

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam.text);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam);
```

You're trying to set the value of the parameter to the textbox itself - not its `.Text` property!

Use this instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need txtnam.Text

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is simple. You forgot to get the text property on `txtnam`, so you are passing the entire textbox object instead of its value.

```
txtnam.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add the `.Text` at this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam);
```

change it to:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtnam.Text);
```